# fading Background images with jquery only allow one picture, how to fade from one background to another background?

Tags: jquery, background, fading

Im not good at js & jquery and im trying to write a fading effect background slider with hover buttons. Code so far i wrote is working but not very much I want. I want to hover the link button would make the background fade to another background image.

However now Ive got is the link button make the background fade out then another background image fade in. Just don't like the blank background at the middle.

```js
$(document).ready( function(){ 
 $('a.one').hover( function(){ 
   $('#bgFader').fadeOut( 'slow', function(){
      $('#bgFader').removeClass().addClass('bg2').fadeIn('slow');
   })
 })
 $('a.one').mouseout( function(){ 
   $('#bgFader').fadeOut( 'slow', function(){
      $('#bgFader').removeClass().addClass('bg1').fadeIn('slow');
   })
 })
});

$(document).ready(function(){ 
 $('a.two').hover( function(){ 
   $('#bgFader').fadeOut( 'slow', function(){
      $('#bgFader').removeClass().addClass('bg3').fadeIn('slow');
   })
 })
 $('a.two').mouseout( function(){ 
   $('#bgFader').fadeOut( 'slow', function(){
      $('#bgFader').removeClass().addClass('bg1').fadeIn('slow');
   })
 })
});
```

```css
#bgFader {
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;          /* or whatever value is good for u */
  z-index: 1;
}
#content {
  background-color: transparent;
  position:absolute;       /* or whatever value is good for u */
  z-index: 10;
}

.bg1{  
  background: transparent url(https://meloholica.files.wordpress.com/2010/02/be-happy.jpg) no-repeat top left scroll;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.bg2{  
  background: transparent url(http://media.mnn.com/sites/default/files/editorial/happy%20habits_0.jpg) no-repeat top left scroll; 
   width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.bg3{  
  background: transparent url(http://fs102.jpe.ru/ff30/4192417_a35633bb.jpg) no-repeat top left scroll; 
   width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="bgFader" class="bg1"></div>
  <div id="content">
    <a class="one" href="#">link1></a>
    <a class="two" href="#">link2></a>
  </div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ming725/1wyzL81p/

Im thinking I should change the .css background instead of the class maybe.

please let me know what you think and thank you for anyone who like to help.